# asterisk phpagi returns busy

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

Right now, I'm having my script to not pick up a call, but on their end, it retries 3 times so my asterisk server gets hit 3 times. How do I may return a busy signal rather than not answering a call? or any other way to prevent their client end from hitting my server 3 times for each call I don't have my agi script answering the call?

Here is part of my script

```
  require_once('phpagi.php');

  $agi = new AGI();
  //$agi->answer();


stuff here

$agi->hangup();
```

Comment: You're really not giving enough information here.  Why is the other caller ringing your system three times?  
Does the other caller have a consistent CallerID or DNIS?

Comment: Hello, yes, it has a consistent CAllerID - I do not know why they are ringing my system 3 times, i just want it to stop :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 variants:

1)

`$agi->exec("Busy","");`

2) Answer before hangup(if prevous not help).

Comment: Looks like sending busy works, but I am trying to stay away from answer to not get charged.

Comment: You not need do Answer if you are dooing Busy. Answer need only if Busy not work for your provider/gate type.

Comment: that's right, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't... answer charges me 1 minute...

Comment: you can do nothing here. except change voip provider. It HAVE work with busy

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  You don't need an AGI for this.  You can use "GosubIf" to test if a call has the same caller ID as your annoyance caller.  Then, use this code:

```
[no_one_home_but_us_chickens]
exten => s,1,Answer ; can't Playtones unless we answer first
 same => n,Playtones(busy) ; send the audio sequence that humans understand means "busy"
 same => n,Busy(10) ; signal the other end that the line is busy.
 same => n,Hangup()
 same => n,Return()
```

... much simpler and gets your job done.
See: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Busy for more information